# ¿Como concatenar campos repetidos en mysql y php?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una tabla donde se repiten campos como el nombre, fecha publicacion, etc y hay campos que no se repiten como rutadeArchivo, ya que inserto varios y me generan distintos nombres para la ruta, logro agrupar todo con group id, pero el problema es que en el campo de las rutas ya no se me muestra todas las que inserte para dicho id, logro agruparlas con "GROUP_CONCAT" pero el problema es que al momento de mostrarlo en mi vista desde php lo toma solo como una ruta y ahí me genera el error, ayudaa es urgente.

este es mi consulta en mysql:

```
SELECT e.idExpediente,
  u.`tipoDoc`,
  u.`nroDoc`,
  u.`correo`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(ar.rutaArchivosAdj SEPARATOR '\n') AS rutaArchivoAdj 
FROM expediente e 
inner join usuario u on e.idusuario = u.idusaurio
```

Este es el codigo en php:

```
  <?php
  $listexped = ControladorUsuarios::ctrListarUsuariosNorm();

  if ($listexped != null) {

   foreach ($listexped as $key => $value) {

   <tr>
     <td class="td_row_text text-center" style="vertical-align:middle;">' . 
     $value["rutaArchivoAdj"] . '</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

En mi vista se muestra así el campo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No sé si tenga que ver con tu error, pero en la consulta SELECT no puede ir una coma ( , ) antes del FROM. Saludos.

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta un ejemplo de los datos originales y la salida esperada.

Comment: no amigo, solo que lo edite ya que hay mucho mas campos solo quiero ver la forma que el campo rutaArchivoAdj se muestre por separado en mi vista, para poder agregarle una etiqueta <a download>

Comment: En $value["rutaArchivoAdj"] tienes una cadena, si el group_concat no indicas separador (por defecto es una coma), en Php podrás hacer un $rutas = explode(",", $value['rutaArchivoAdj'], así en $rutas tendrás un array con todas las rutas y haciendo un for puedes construir <tr><td>

Comment: me sale este error "array to string conversion"

Comment: Es por que es un array... haz un var_dump de la variable para que veas como quedo.